# How to keep display: block; working inbetween media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu button that when you click on it under 960px, it will toggle a menu. That menu is permantly shown on a screen that is over 960px. The problem is when I click on the menu to open, and then I close the menu under 960px, when I increase the screen size the menu isn't there because the last action was to close the menu ( when the screen is under 960px. ) How do I make sure that the menu stays open above 960px no matter what state the menu is in under 960px?

Javascript:

```
     $('.leftnavmenu').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(window).width() <= 960) {
        $('.left-nav-main-li.active div:nth-child(3)').slideToggle();
    } else { ($(window).width() >= 960) 
        $('left-nav ul.navigation>li>div').show();
    }
    });
```

HTML

```
   <div class="left-nav>
       <span class="leftnavmenu>Select</span>
       <div style="display: none;">
       <ul>...</ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: 1) You're missing a `.` before `left-nav` in your else statement. 2) You're always going to slideToggle if equal to 960px with your current code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with a CSS media query

```
//More than 960px
@media (min-width: 960px){
    .left-nav ul.navigation>li>div {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Keith Would you be able to create a JSFiddle with the full implementation of the menu?